# Can anyone please explain this password complexity regexp to me?

Tags: regex

```
\A(?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[a-z])(?=\S*?[0-9])\S{6,}\z
```

(this comes from the JGSoft flavor of regexp).

Basically, the objective of this regexp is this: "Password complexity
Tests if the input consists of 6 or more characters.
The input must contain at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter and one digit."

So there are three groups that could be placed in any order (first capital letters, then noncapital letters, then digits). \A matches the start of a string and \z matches the end of the string. I'm sort of confused about the (?= part. It's supposed to be a positive lookahead. I don't see how this regexp allows you to type the password characters in any order though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you get the basic idea. Think about it like this:

1. Look from the start of the text. While on the start:

   1. Check there's at least one upper case letter (just by looking, don't advance).
   2. Check there's at least one lower case letter.
   3. Check there's at least one digit.
2. Match at least 6 non-whitesapce characters to the end.

Look-aheads aren't capturing - you stay on the same location (the start, in this case), and check if you *could* match this forward - that's why the order doesn't matter

Here's an example, for the input `1@34Ab`.

1. `\A` - matches the start of the string. great.
2. `(?=\S*?[A-Z])` - `\S*?[A-Z]` can match `1@34A`, the `(?=)` assertion succeeds.
3. `(?=\S*?[a-z])` - can match `1@34Ab`.
4. `(?=\S*?[0-9])` - can match `1`.
5. `\S{6,}` - Matches 1@34Ab, all the way to the end (`\z`).

Answer (score 1):

Lookahead means that I test if there is a pattern without changing may location so

1. it test if from the beginning of the
   string there is zero or more none
   white space followed by upper case
   latter.
2. then it checks again from the
   beginning of the string if there is
   zero or more none white space
   followed by lower case latter.
3. then it checks again from the
   beginning of the string if there is
   zero or more none white space
   followed by numeric.
4. lastly it checks if the string is 6
   or more none white space characters.

the first 3 tests (upper case, lower case, numeric) lookahead - the check is from the beginning of the string without changing location only the last test (6 or more characters) changes the location.
lookahead is its name says just look and see what comes without moving so the first 3 test are performed from the beginning of the string so the order is not important as long as all 3 are positive