# String regex not working

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex in c sharp to check if supplied password is

- more than 10 characters
- should have at least one lowercase character
- should have at least one Uppercase character
- Should have either a number or a special character

---

```
Regex.IsMatch(password, "^.*(?=.{10,})(?=.*[0-9]|[@#$%^&+=])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$")
```

Why wouldn't the above work?

its taking `abcdefgh123` but not `abcdefgh&+`

Comment: It might be easier with 3 separate regex checks and a length check.  But why do you want to implement restrictions like this in the first place?  10 characters is a lot.

Comment: Since you are testing multiple properties of the password, I would advice you to split it up into several regexen. This will also help you tell the user the reason that the password is not accepted.

Comment: You could use the regex (tweaked slightly) from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612404/can-anyone-please-explain-this-password-complexity-regexp-to-me)...

Comment: @jjnguy WHy wouldn't it work?

Comment: @Rocky, you say that it must have an uppercase letter and neither of your example do.  You also state 'either a number of a special character' which implies only one of those.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I'd do a separate check for the length and then one check for each of the character requirements.  I don't like to use overly complicated regular expressions when things can be done in a more readable manner.

```
if (password.Length > 10 && 
    Regex.IsMatch(password, "[a-b]") && 
    Regex.IsMatch(password, "[A-Z]") && 
    Regex.IsMatch(password, "[0-9@#$%^&+=]"))
{
    //Valid password
}
```

Comment: +1 for readability. Maintaining code with unreadable regexen is extremely expensive - especially since most programmers have a faint (if any) understanding of regular expressions.

Comment: Should mention that although more readable, this implementation is slightly slower than a single regex statement because password will get evaluated 3 times rather than once.  But depending on the situation performance may not be a consideration.

Comment: Very simple and elegant. Thanks! Exactly what I need

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably in `(?=.*[0-9]|[@#$%^&+=])`, which means `.*[0-9]` OR `[@#$%^&+=]` - it should be `.*[0-9@#$%^&+=]`.

Also, you don't really need `.*` twice in your regex, and can use `.{10,}` as the main expression, so this should be the same:

```
^(?=.*[0-9@#$%^&+=])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{10,}$
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need an additional paren around the "number or symbol" bit

`^.*(?=.{10,})(?=.*([0-9]|[@#$%^&+=]))(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$`

http://regexr.com?2srhm

Answer (score 1):

If you want a code solution, an alternative might be:

```
if (password.Length >= 10 &&
    password.Any(Char.IsLower) &&
    password.Any(Char.IsUpper) &&
    password.Any(c=>Char.IsDigit(c) || Char.IsSymbol(c)))
    {

    }
```

Note that these functions include Unicode characters. Which is awesome for a password. If that's a problem, you may use:

```
if (password.Length >= 10 &&
    password.Any(c => (c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) &&
    password.Any(c => (c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')) &&
    password.Any(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || "@#$%^&+=".Contains(c)))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
`/^(?=.{10,})(?=.*[[:lower:]])(?=.*[[:upper:]])(?=.*[0-9@#$%^&+=])/`

Expanded:

```
 /^  
   (?= .{10,} )
   (?= .*[[:lower:]] )
   (?= .*[[:upper:]] )
   (?= .*[0-9@#$%^&+=] )
  /x;
```

Edit - added 0-9, missed that requirement